# How to schedule (assign) the elements (inner lists) of 2 lists based on certain delay or condition?

Tags: python-3.x, list, timezone, scheduling

How to schedule (assign) the elements (inner lists) of 2 lists based on certain delay or condition?

I was able to do the following.

```
import time, json
import datetime

l1 = [["a1"], ["b1", "c1"], ["d1","e1", "f1"], ["g1", "h1", "i1", "j1"]]
l2 = [["a2"], ["b2", "c2"], ["d2","e2", "f2"], ["g2", "h2", "i2", "j2"]]
pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
date_time = '2023-06-27 00:00:00'
delay1 = 600
delay2 = 86400
task_period = 1800
output = {}

for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    epoch1 = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(str(date_time), pattern)))
    epoch2 = epoch1 + delay2
    t1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch1)
    t2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch2)
    for k, l in zip(i, j):
        output[k] = str(t1)
        output[l] = str(t2)
    date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        epoch1 + task_period + delay1)

print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"a1": "2023-06-27 00:00:00",
"a2": "2023-06-28 00:00:00",
"b1": "2023-06-27 00:40:00",
"b2": "2023-06-28 00:40:00",
"c1": "2023-06-27 00:40:00",
"c2": "2023-06-28 00:40:00",
"d1": "2023-06-27 01:20:00",
"d2": "2023-06-28 01:20:00",
"e1": "2023-06-27 01:20:00",
"e2": "2023-06-28 01:20:00",
"f1": "2023-06-27 01:20:00",
"f2": "2023-06-28 01:20:00",
"g1": "2023-06-27 02:00:00",
"g2": "2023-06-28 02:00:00",
"h1": "2023-06-27 02:00:00",
"h2": "2023-06-28 02:00:00",
"i1": "2023-06-27 02:00:00",
"i2": "2023-06-28 02:00:00",
"j1": "2023-06-27 02:00:00",
"j2": "2023-06-28 02:00:00"
```

}

additional info:

```
delay1 : delay between each inner lists of both lists l1 and l2, as shown below

         (["a1"] <==> ["b1", "c1"] <==> ["d1","e1", "f1"] so on)
         (["a2"] <==> ["b2", "c2"] <==> ["d2","e2", "f2"] so on)

delay2 : delay between corresponding inner lists of l1 and l2 (["a1"] <==> ["a2"], ["b1", "c1"] <==> ["b2", "c2"], so on)
wait_period is something that can be added to each
```

In the above example, I considered a specific time (`date_time`).
`t1 = {"a1" : "Australia/Adelaide", "a2": "Australia/Adelaide", "b1": "Asia/Calcutta", "c1":"Asia/Calcutta", "b2":"Asia/Calcutta", "c2":"Asia/Calcutta", "d1": "America/Caracas", "d2":"Australia/South", "e1" : "America/Caracas", "f1":"America/Caracas", "e2":"Australia/South", "f2":"Australia/South"}` etc
Now, If those elements to be scheduled within specific time frame wrt **time zone** of respective elements.

```
start = 22 (11 PM)
end = 2    (2 AM) ==> Considering last element to be scheduled at (1:30 AM), ensuring task completed within 2AM (end), 1800.
```

If there are more elements and if they can't be scheduled within one day, that should be followed for next day with the provided hours.
Any normalization by converting each different timezones to UTC and align with that?

I am trying my best and arrived at above solution.

Comment: I don't see you setting a timezone anywhere in your code?
 (--> [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) library offers the necessary implementation / objects)